# Django 1.7 python manage.py makemigrations polls

Tags: python, django

I study Django tutorial and i have some strange error when i run console command. 
0001_initial.py not created in migration folder.

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls


C:\Users\pc\Dropbox\ГуглДрайв\python\projects\pools\mysite> python manage.py makemigrations polls
    Migrations for 'polls':
      0001_initial.py:
        - Create model Choice
        - Create model Question
        - Add field question to choice
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", lin
    rom_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", lin
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 28

        self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 33
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\makemigr
    4, in handle
        self.write_migration_files(changes)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\makemigr
    3, in write_migration_files
        migrations_directory = os.path.dirname(writer.path)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrations\writer.py", line 21
        return os.path.join(basedir, self.filename)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 84, in join
        result_path = result_path + p_path
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whatw wrong?

this is my models.py file in polls folder

```
# -- coding: utf-8 -

from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: 1)did you create database with default ut8 encoding?
2) did you add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in the top of models etc?

Comment: Hi, Mike! I dont know - i use default SQLlite base

Comment: What's the version of your python interpreter?

Comment: It would help if you can post the code in your settings, models here.

Comment: Yes i added # -- coding: utf-8 # -- coding: utf-8 # -- coding: utf-8 in the top to models.py

Comment: django 1.7, python 2.7.8

Comment: # -- coding: utf-8 -

from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

Comment: I suspect the problem lies with 'ГуглДрайв'. Try to run your project from a folder that doesn't have any Russian names in the path. If you use a virtualenv, then put that in an ASCII-only path as well. Note that a virtualenv often breaks when moved; it needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem lies with 'ГуглДрайв'. Try to run your project from a folder that doesn't have any Russian names in the path. If you use a virtualenv, then put that in an ASCII-only path as well. Note that a virtualenv often breaks when moved; it needs to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thijs van Dien's suspicion.  You are probably hitting this issue:

https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/457

There's a fix here that you might try if you don't want to rename ГуглДрайв:

https://github.com/atykhonov/virtualenv/commit/b3b51ccfd8a3863b028804df9ffc0ae832a60873